# A listing according to Rambam's four categories of mitzvos

Tags: jewish-books, rambam, mitzvah

The **Rambam** in [*Shoresh* 9](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Shorashim.9?lang=bi) of **Sefer HaMitzvos** says that there are four categories of *mitzvos*:

> דע שכל צוויי התורה ואזהרותיה הנה הם בארבעה דברים. בדעות ובפעולות ובמדות ובדבור

1. *Deos* (Beliefs, Attitudes, Thoughts)
2. *Peulos* (Actions)
3. *Middos* (Character traits)
4. *Dibbur* (Speech)

In the *sefer* itself, the **Rambam** doesn't categorize his list of 613 *mitzvos* by these categories. I was wondering if anyone ever did? Sometimes it's not obvious how to categorize them (for example, ואהבת לרעך כמוך, loving one's neighbor like onself, is *deos*, *middos*, and consists of *peulos*).

Comment: Maybe it's clear from other stuff he wrote that the commands can be so divided. But not from the part that you quote: that sounds like all the commands, or at least some, have these four aspects.

Comment: @msh210 In the continuation, which I linked to, he seems to say a mitzvah fits into one of these types. Perhaps you're right he's not excluding the possibility that a mitzvah could be multiple in categories. I still would like a list, regardless.